# CardLayout appearing without asking for it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

This is my SSCE (though in three seperate classes).

StartUp.java

```
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame gui = new MainFrame();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
package gui;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menuRoboControl;
    private JMenuItem menuItemStart;
    private JMenuItem menuItemShutdown;
    private JPanel cardPanel;
    private final JPanel comListCard = new ComListCard();

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void menuItemStartActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "selectPort");

    }

    private void menuItemShutdownActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        mainFrame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuRoboControl = new JMenu();
        menuItemStart = new JMenuItem();
        menuItemShutdown = new JMenuItem();
        cardPanel = new JPanel();

        //======== mainFrame ========
        {
            Container mainFrameContentPane = mainFrame.getContentPane();
            mainFrameContentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainFrameContentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            //======== menuBar ========
            {

                //======== menuRoboControl ========
                {
                    menuRoboControl.setText("RoboControl");

                    //---- menuItemStart ----
                    menuItemStart.setText("Start Robot");
                    menuItemStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            menuItemStartActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                    });
                    menuRoboControl.add(menuItemStart);

                    //---- menuItemShutdown ----
                    menuItemShutdown.setText("Shutdown Robot");
                    menuItemShutdown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            menuItemShutdownActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                    });
                    menuRoboControl.add(menuItemShutdown);
                }
                menuBar.add(menuRoboControl);
            }
            mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            //======== cardPanel ========
            {
                cardPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
                cardPanel.add(comListCard, "selectPort");
            }

            mainFrameContentPane.add(cardPanel);
            mainFrame.setSize(835, 635);
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

ComListCard.java

```
package gui;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ComListCard extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea portInfo;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
    private JList<String> portList;
    private JButton selectPort;

    public ComListCard() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        portInfo = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        portList = new JList<>();
        selectPort = new JButton();

        //======== comListCard ========
        {
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            ((GridBagLayout) this.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[]{298, 214, 0, 0};
            ((GridBagLayout) this.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 220, 0, 0, 0};
            ((GridBagLayout) this.getLayout()).columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};
            ((GridBagLayout) this.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};

            //---- portInfo ----
            portInfo.setText("Select the port connected to your XBee. If you do not know what port it is connected to, check your Device Manager.");
            portInfo.setLineWrap(true);
            portInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            portInfo.setOpaque(false);
            portInfo.setEnabled(false);
            portInfo.setEditable(false);
            portInfo.setBorder(null);
            this.add(portInfo, new GridBagConstraints(1, 4, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

            //======== scrollPane1 ========
            {

                //---- portList ----
                portList.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
                    String[] values = {
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4"
                    };

                    @Override
                    public int getSize() {
                        return values.length;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getElementAt(int i) {
                        return values[i];
                    }
                });
                scrollPane1.setViewportView(portList);
            }
            this.add(scrollPane1, new GridBagConstraints(1, 5, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

            //---- selectPort ----
            selectPort.setText("Select");
            this.add(selectPort, new GridBagConstraints(1, 6, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Now some information on the problem. GUI works fine, purely about the CardLayout. As you can see I created a main window with a JPanel inside acting as the holder of the card. I created a card and have added it too to CardLayout. But it already appears from the start of the program while it should only appear after pressing the button (referring to the actionlistener where I put .show(..).

Any help appreciated. Not in a hurry either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CardLayout` is designed to "hold" multiple cards (panels), but only one card will ever be displayed at a time. The key is that "one" of the panels is always displayed. So the CardLayout is functioning properly.

If you has an application that needs to dynamically display an panel on a frame then you must add the panel at run time. In this case the basic logic would be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

With the above approach, space is not reserved on the frame for the panel when the frame is initially displayed (so you may also need to pack() the frame to make sure the panel is visible).

If you really want to see an empty space for your card panel when the frame is displayed, then you could simply create a panel with no components added to it and then add this panel to your CardLayout. Then when you invoke the show() method, you will swap in your panel with the components.

Comment: Ah stupid me. Used CardLayouts before and never had a problem with them. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: *"If you has an application that needs to dynamically display an panel on a frame.."*  In a `CardLayout`, that can be *simulated* by adding one blank panel, and displaying it by default.